# How to use Redux connect along with multiple React providers in a React Class component?

Tags: redux, react-redux

In a React component using Redux I want to use withCookies and withAuth0 providers in addition to Redux connect().

```
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { withAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

class TopBarRedux extends React.Component<any, any>{
...

export const TopBar = withCookies(
  withAuth0(
    connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps,
    )(TopBarRedux)
  )
)
```

However, when the component is used

```
<TopBar />
```

componentDidMount() is called but componentDidUpdate() is never called. Is the syntax or sequence of the export const incorrect?

Comment: Are you mutating state in the redux reducer?

Comment: @HMR you are correct. It turned out to be a problem w/ the sequence of mutating state not firing ComponentDidUpdate. Thanks.